# How do I get the table names prefixing the column names automatically for the output data of my sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `select *`  multiple tables and want to prefix the column names with the table names (since some tables have columns with the same names). How do I do this?

Comment: you add an alias after every table name in the `FROM` clause, eg `FROM table AS t` and then you can prefix its columns with the alias `t`, eg `t.column_name`. See the manual [7.2.1.2. Table And Column Aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

Comment: Thanks. Any way to not have to specify each column manually? I have a lot of columns.

Comment: You can also define alias for the columns of the table in the `FROM` clause, eg `FROM table AS t(c1, c2, c3, c4)` and then refer to these alias in the `SELECT` clause, eg `SELECT t.c1, t.c2, t.c3, t.c4` or simply `SELECT t.*` for selecting all the columns of table `t`.

Comment: There is no way to get that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias:

```
SELECT t1.c1 AS t1_c1
 , t2.c1 AS t2_c1
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.b;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I have a ton of columns, and want them all. Any way to automate this by not having the specify each column?

Comment: @imagineerThat maybe you should imagineer that. Sorry for the bad pun. I'm sure you can query column names from somewhere, and/or use excel creatively. That's what I usually do